# PowerShell Defrag Analysis returning NULL values

Tags: windows, powershell, hard-drive

PowerShell Defrag Analysis returning NULL values

```
$computer = "Server"
$drives = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock { Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem | Select-Object @{n = "Name"; e = { $_.Root.TrimEnd("\") } } }
$drives.Name | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host $_
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock { param($_) 
        $volume = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Volume -Filter "DriveLetter = '$_'"
        Write-Host $volume
        $fragmentation = $volume.DefragAnalysis() 
        $Props = @{
            FragmentationStatusFor = $($volume.Name)
            TotalFragmentedFiles   = $($fragmentation.TotalFiles)
            TotalFragmentedBytes   = $($fragmentation.TotalBytes)
        }
        New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Props
    } -ArgumentList $_, $volume
} | Select-Object * | Write-DbaDataTable -SqlInstance SomeServer -Database SomeDB -Schema GET -Table DbaDefragAnalysis -AutoCreateTable -Confirm -KeepNulls -bulkCopyTimeOut 180 -ErrorAction Continue -Verbose -EnableException;
```

TotalFragmentedFiles returns no value
TotalFragmentedBytes returns no value

Comment: Can you re-format your question so the code fences (i.e 3 x backticks) are on a separate line on their own - it’ll appear as a block of code then rather than word-wrapped inline…

Comment: Why are you using a oneliner for something like this? In my 10 years of using PS extensively I've never had a use case where I'd use a oneliner over a "normal" script. Oneliners make it extremely hard to debug your code and find errors. My advise: format the script so you can actually debug and troubleshoot the problem you're facing.

Comment: @bluuf apologies the code is not a one liner but was in the way I used the code block.

Comment: ```param($_)``` doesn’t look right to me. Even if it *works* it’d be very unusual to use the ```$_``` “automatic variable”’s name (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.3#_ ) as a parameter name - I’d suggest something like ```$driveLetter``` instead. Also, you’re passing *two* arguments in (```-ArgumentList $_, $volume```) but only receiving one (```param($_)```, if that even works) so there’s a code smell there as well…

Comment: Please [do not](https://www.hp.com/us-en/shop/tech-takes/what-does-defragging-do) defrag an SSD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to retrieve a property of the `Win32_DefragAnalysis` WMI class that do not exist, check the [Microsoft Documentation for Win32_DefragAnalysis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/vdswmi/win32-defraganalysis), there is no property called `TotalBytes`, that's why you are getting no return values.

To get the values that you are trying to fetch, you should probably follow [this article of the MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/vdswmi/defrag-method-in-class-win32-volume)